# Eclipse/XDebug Step Over Misbehaving

Tags: php, eclipse, wordpress, xdebug

I am debugging a WordPress site with Eclipse and XDebug.

When I debug it as a php web application, program execution stops at my breakpoint as it should. But when I click Step Over, my program execution pointer disappears.

I have to click in the stack frame on the calling procedure, then click back on the currently executing procedure to make the program execution pointer come back. So I need 3 clicks instead of one for each line I step over.

The most bizarre thing is that I can step through the WordPress php files with no issues, however, as soon as I debug my own php files, the debugger misbehaves!

What could be causing this?

Ubuntu 14,
Eclipse Neon,
XDebug,
php 7.0

Comment: best place for such bug report is PDT bugzilla. We will help ;)  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT

Comment: Done. Thanks! ;^)

Comment: Probably Bartlomiej (our debugger specialist) help you :P